# Recieving a FormData object as a node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I have an HTML form with two buttons (along with other text input areas), and I have some front end javascript code to handle the submit. On the submit, I create a FormData object and store the file in it. Then I send that through an jquery ajax request to a node.js server. However, this is where the problem is - when I try to access the file in the server, the file is always undefined - i've tried accessing it with `req.body, req.files, req.file` but its always undefined. Is this a problem with the ajax request, or the way i'm receiving it?

upload file button:

```
<input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element file required" accept="application/pdf" type="file"/>
```

submit button:

```
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

handle submit:

```
$('#form_1039889').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var file = $('#element_3').get(0).files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('pdf', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPdf',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
           //success TODO code
        }
    });
});
```

relevant server code:

```
app.post('/addPdf', function(req, res) {
    console.log("file: " + req.body.pdf);
});
```

EDIT:
Here's my (relevant) code when I try and use multer:

```
app.post('/addPdf', [multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
    console.log("file: " + req.file);
}]);
```

Comment: What does console.log(req.body) give you?

Comment: What middleware are you using?

Comment: Console.log(req.body) gives me undefined

Comment: I was using multer, but that didn't work either so now I'm not using any.

Comment: You have to use some middleware, otherwise `req.body`, etc. won't be populated. If you were using `multer`, perhaps you should post the code from when you were using that.